# I want to sort the array in wave form but it says int is not subscriptable

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting, arraylist, compare-and-swap

**Here is my code**

```
def wave(arr):
  for indx,el in enumerate(arr):
    if indx != 0 and indx%2 == 0:
      if el[indx] < el[indx-1]:
        arr[indx-1], arr[indx]= arr[indx],arr[indx-1]
      if el[indx] < el[indx+1]:
        arr[indx], arr[indx+1]= arr[indx+1],arr[indx]
  return arr

li = [3,5,12,5,3]
print(wave(li))
```

*The logic i am using here is to compare the even element from their side element and swap accordingly.*

Answer (score 0):

If you check the type of your `el` variable, you can see it is an integer (`<class 'int'>` ). So your try do this this: `int[int]`. It is non-sense and not possible in Python.

You can check it:

```
def wave(arr):
    for indx, el in enumerate(arr):
        print(type(el))  # <class 'int'>
        ....
```

I have tried to find out your expectation (You didn't write your expectation in your question) and I have written a working code with several comments.

**Code:**

```
def wave(arr):
    for indx, el in enumerate(arr):
        # If the index is not zero AND the element is even AND element is not the last one
        if indx != 0 and indx % 2 == 0 and indx != len(arr) - 1:
            if arr[indx] < arr[indx - 1]:  # If the left side is greater
                arr[indx - 1], arr[indx] = arr[indx], arr[indx - 1]
            if arr[indx] < arr[indx + 1]:  # If the right side is greater
                arr[indx], arr[indx + 1] = arr[indx + 1], arr[indx]
    return arr


li = [3, 5, 12, 5, 3]
print(wave(li))  # expected: [3, 5, 12, 5, 3]

li = [3, 5, 12, 15, 3, 8]
print(wave(li))  # expected: [3, 5, 15, 3, 12, 8]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
[3, 5, 12, 5, 3]
[3, 5, 15, 3, 12, 8]
```